# Testing non-opaque error values

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

Is there a best practice for comparing non-opaque error values in Go?

Most code bases seem to treat errors as opaque (either the operation succeeded or it failed, with no visibility into internal details about what caused the error).

This makes it easy to write unit tests since all you need to do is assert the actual error against the expected error. The most I've seen people do in addition to that is compare error strings to make sure that it includes at minimum some key information. For example:

```
if err == nil || !strings.Contains(err.Error(), "not found in the Raft configuration") {
  t.Fatalf("err: %v", err)
}
```

But for cases where the additional error information is needed (like in form validation where you need to specify the invalid field name, the value, an error code and possibly some nested errors too), what do you do?

I can't simply do a `reflect.DeepEqual()` since the error will contain a unique stack trace which will make the comparison fail every time. Also, having nested errors makes the testing logic even more complex and you'll need all kinds of error-prone logic (loops, recursion) to compare the desired fields. Is there a standard way of testing errors of this nature?

Comment: Those values that aren't "deterministic" you could check for their presence to make sure that they were set, then set them to their zero value (`""`, `nil`, etc.) before passing the rest to `reflect.DeepEqual`. Not ideal, but works.

Answer (score 1):

While this may not answer your question pertaining to checking errors that are not done the right way, here is at least an example of how to create and use errors the right way.

What is commonly done in the standard library packages is errors are created as exported variables and then those can be thrown and compared. Here is an example... however unimaginative it may be.

https://play.golang.org/p/JlpguFn2NX

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

var ErrBadIdea = errors.New("that was dumb")
var ErrNoValue = errors.New("not a real value")

func DoSomething(i int) error {
    if i == 0 {
        return ErrNoValue
    }
    if i < 0 {
        return ErrBadIdea
    }
    // does something that doesn't like negative or zero values
    return nil
}

func main() {
    err := DoSomething(-1)
    fmt.Println(err == ErrBadIdea, err)
    err = DoSomething(0)
    fmt.Println(err == ErrNoValue, err)
}
```

An excellent example of this is in the `database/sql` package of the standard library.

https://godoc.org/database/sql#pkg-variables

These variables exist so you can test like so

```
if err == sql.ErrNoRows { // these are not the rows you are looking for }
```

It gets better!

Because `error` is an `interface`, all you have to do is implement it. Which only requires you have a `func Error() string`. See the following example and marvel at the power of `interface`s.

https://play.golang.org/p/3RFrxKGkdm

Also read the following blog about errors.

https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go

Comment: Thanks for looking at the question. I'm curious as to what you would consider 'not right' about this type of custom error. What alternative is there when you have an error that requires more context than just a simple error string? Like the above example when you have a JSON endpoint that return specific error codes and reasons for the failure. How can this be accomplished with just error variables?

Comment: The problem is that people code along and decide "this is an error case", so they lazily do this `if something { return errors.New("bad") }`. Then they post their library on github for the masses to use. But the error returned is completely worthless, it only tells you something went wrong. The problem then propagates and people continue to do this and now we have a crapton of worthless errors being returned. Also, you CAN return more useful errors because you only have to implement the `Error()` interface. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: As far as dealing with these worthless errors, you probably will just have to string match them and hope whatever library tossed it doesn't decide to change the wording.

Comment: See new edit and note that sometimes when a seemingly simple `error` is returned, there can be far more than initially meets the eye.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much the solution I arrived at. It was between Dave Cheney's suggestion (asserting on error behaviours instead of concrete types) and type casting, but I found that casting the error to a concrete type to be the only viable way in this type of scenario. So really, the only way to compare errors of this type would be either to zero-out the non-deterministic fields as @mkopriva suggests, or just manually compare whatever field you're interested in. I don't know... I can't help but feel this is a hacky way of doing things.

Comment: It'd look something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/sjNb_9Gb35) and i've never seen any Go app with error testing like that